# Kubernetes MACVLAN attached devices cluster IP address

Tags: kubernetes

I apologise if this question has been asked already or if it is a silly one, I could not find its answer online. I am interested in deploying a Kub. cluster which uses a network attached definition (MacVLAN) to enable pods to interact with external real devices plugged in the Kub’s machines’ interfaces (or reachable by).

I'd like to see the Kub. cluster assigning IP addresses to these devices as if they were PODS.

Is there any documentation around that might point me into the right direction ?

What I am trying to avoid is to have a POD acting as a DHCP server in my cluster and I’d like to leverage Kub’s functionalities to achieve the same effect.

Thanks,

Comment: Consider to ask sys-admin and networking questions on https://serverfault.com instead. Stack Overflow is for programming questions.